# Extract property from exception?

Tags: python

```
try:
   err_obj = {
      "a": 123,
      "b": 456,
   }
   raise Exception(err_obj)
except Exception as ex:
   # how can I extract a or b from ex?
   print(ex)
```

How can I extract a or b from ex? Thanks.

Comment: Check `ex.args`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is under the [`args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException.args) tuple as a dict (because you raised with one):

```
>>> ex.args
({'a': 123, 'b': 456},)

>>> ex.args[0]["a"]
123

>>> ex.args[0]["b"]
456
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either create a custom exception type as has been answered already which isn't a bad choice, but if you don't want to go through that you can access the arguments of your exception through `.args` like so:

```py
try:
   err_obj = {
      "a": 123,
      "b": 456,
   }
   raise Exception(err_obj)
except Exception as ex:
   # how can I extract a or b from ex?
   print(ex.args[0]['a'], ex.args[0]['b'])
```

(just altered your code a bit)

Answer (score 1):

Create a [custom exception type](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions) that has your desired members.

```
class DataException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
 
try:
    raise DataException(a=123, b=456)
except DataException as e:
    print(e.a, e.b)
```

Comment: What if I don't want to define a new type?